# Efficient way to extract key values using C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

We get token key values in the following format shown below. What is the efficient way to  extract the amount and currency code key values?. I am trying to use Split method but not sure if that is the best way.

```
"{\"Amount\":12.0,\"CurrencyCode\":\"840\"}"
```

Comment: This format (apart from the backslashes which are most likely not actually part of the string but just part of the display) is called [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), and there are many libraries out there for parsing JSON with .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use JSON.NET http://www.newtonsoft.com/json . Is a popular JSON parser for .NET. You can call JObject.Parse ("yourtext"); and then you can inspect your JSON. For documentation, please follow this link http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm.

Happy coding!